# c#, ADFS, sso and OAuth2 : how to?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I'm working on a front-end app which is developped in C# and which is supposed to access some WS. Those WS are developped in Java.

To access those WS, user must be logged. The authentication system uses sso (ssocircle) and ADFS.

The front and back (WS) are supposed to use OAuth2;
I'm all new to those technologies and cannot find an example or tutorial which explain everything.

I have a front mock which is in java (springOauthClient) which works perfectly : when i try to access a WS, i'm redirected on the ssocircle auth form, and then when i put my login/password, i'm redirected back to the mock, and get the WS results, then i can call others WS without being redirected to the login form again.

What i'm trying to do now is to implement the real client (front), in c#, with OAuth2 but i have no idea what to do.

I've tried :

```
string completeUrl2 = "http://localhost:8080/volta-rest-webservices/oauth/authorize?client_id=volta-client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:63441/&response_type=code&scope=read%20write&state=kz3Ylz";

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(completeUrl2);




        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            return Redirect(response.ResponseUri.OriginalString);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            //TODO log
        }
```

And i'm redirected to the login form, i put my login/password, authentication is working well, but when i'm supposed to be redirected back to my front app, i get a 405 error : "Request method 'POST' not supported" ... The page url is then : http://localhost:8080/volta-rest-webservices/saml/SSO

By the way i'm not sure that this is the correct url to call, am i supposed to call the oauth/token_access before oauth/authorize? I'm not sure about the params as well...

Is this the correct way to do, just call some url or do i have to use some external libraries??

I'm quite confused...